# Is there a jQuery construct for "if (typeof someVar === 'undefined')"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does jQuery provide a way to to that test in a more concise way?

**Update**
I should have left jQuery out of this.  It is just an issue of JavaScript.  It's been so long for me!  I am testing to see is something externally-defined module was loaded or not.  It appears that I can just use this instead:

```
if (window.someVar)
```

Please correct me if this is a bad practice.  In my case, if someVar is defined, it will be an object.  It will not be defined to false.

Comment: What for? What's not already concise enough about that if statement?

Comment: http://typeofnan.blogspot.com/2011/01/typeof-is-fast.html

Comment: Yes, if `someVar` will always only interest you as an object, then `window.someVar` would work unless some other code defines `window.someVar` with a truthy value.

Comment: I don't know which answer to accept.  I did a bad job asking my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer must be at least 30 characters and the answer is: No.

Comment: The word you are looking for is 
"Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo!"

Comment: @jAndy: Well, if you limit yourself to a jQuery based solution, then the answer is clearly "no". But there certainly are more concise ways to write it.

Comment: @jAndy like doing `if (someVar === void window.undefined = true)`. Best check for `undefined`.

Comment: @patrick: true, but the question is so simple. Anyway I'm wondering nobody mentioned `jQuery.type()` here.

Comment: @Raynos: what do you mean with "best" ?

Comment: @jAndy: Yeah, but `jQuery.type()` returns a string, so you'd need to do `jQuery.type( someVar ) == "undefined"`, which isn't any more concise. ;o)

Comment: @jAndy I'm really not sure. I think I mean "Worst"

Comment: @Raynos: whatever.. "best" is pretty unclear. best for performance? best for convinience? best for to make you feel good?

Comment: @jAndy it was supposed to be sarcasm and/or a joke.

Answer (score 1):

If it is acceptable in your code to consider `null` and `undefined` to be equal, you could avoid the `typeof` by doing an `==` test on `null`, which will also be `true` for `undefined`.

```
if( someVar == null ) {
    // it was either null or undefined 
}
```

Comment: @Raynos: I assume OP is using `typeof` to avoid the possible issues with `undefined` being redefined. My *personal* opinion is that if `undefined` has been defined, the code *should* break.

Comment: @patrickdw I assume the OP didn't know better. Use closures to get your own copy of `undefined`. The common use-case of `typeof` is to test for undeclared variables.

Comment: @Raynos: Yes, I would prefer to define an `undefined` parameter as well.

Comment: @Raynos: Maybe it's just me, but it seems like if you try to use an undeclared variable, your code should break. At least with the redefining issue, the cause could be someone else's code.

Comment: @patrickdw there's nothing wrong with checking for `undefined` it's perfectly acceptable. you could also check for `void 0`

Comment: @Raynos: When did I say that there's something wrong with checking for `undefined`? My point was that I assumed OP was using `typeof` for a reason.

Comment: Not really.  I didn't know that if( someVar == null ) was equivalent in most cases.

Comment: @patrickdw Nowhere as it turned out. Yes using an undeclared variable deserves breaking code. horrible design failure. If someone has the nerve to put `window.undefined = true` in his code I think we should go to his house and teach him a lesson.

Comment: @Fantius that checks for `null` & `undefined`. Most of the time you don't find `null` in the [wild](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748429/when-to-check-for-undefined-and-when-to-check-for-null). So it's pretty safe.

Comment: I don't understand.  Chrome is failing on both "if (someVar == null)" and "if (someVar != null)" for the undefined someVar.

Comment: @Fantius: Has `someVar` been declared before you're using it in the `if()`? Using `typeof` obscures the fact that it hasn't been declared. What errors do you see in the console?

Comment: No, it's undeclared.  I'm testing to see if it was declared in a module which may or may not be loaded.

Comment: @Fantius then check whether it exists in global scope i.e. `if (window.someVar === undefined)`

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(params, undefined) {
    // ...
    if (someVar === undefined) {
        ...
    }
    ...
    window.SomethingGlobal = SomethingGlobal;
}(params));
```

You can set declare `undefined` as a variable in your function. If that paramater is not passed in then you can garantuee it has the value of `undefined`.

It is always best to use closures like this to create a unique scope. If you need to hoist anything to global scope set it on the window manually.

Alternatively this will work:

```
if (someVar = void 0) {
   ...
}
```

`void` is a funny command. It expects an expression, It runs the expression and always returns `undefined` rather then the `return value` of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real way to make that more concise. Since that code tests if the variable `someVar` is declared, the only safe use of the name `someVar` is as the operand to `typeof` (all other uses will raise an error if the variable is not declared).

I guess you *could* make the rest of the expression somewhat shorter by using a function:

```
function isUndefined(type)
{
    return type === 'undefined';
}

if (isUndefined(typeof someVar)) {
    // ...
}
```

But that's probably not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the 'big varity' of `typeof` includes such 'genius'*ionically* thing like `object`  you may consider about this cheat:

`typeof someVar >= 'u'`ndefine

that will quicken stringcompare but decreases readability and cleanness of your code.

However short is beautify and maybe it's good to remind by that there is such a thing like the `>=`and `=<`-operator for strings that is often forgotten and so not used. ;)