# Why is my JS only working if I put it after the HTML, even though I have a window.onload?

Tags: javascript, html

I just started a CS class at school, so please excuse my total lack of basic knowledge. This JS only works if I put it after the HTML code, not if I put it in the headtag. Shouldn't the window.onload take care of that? Can someone please explain what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
    #field {
        width: 600;
        height: 600;
        background-color: black;
        position: relative;
    }

    #player {
        width: 50;
        height: 50;
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    }
</style>
<script>
    var player = document.getElementById("player");
    var playerLeft = 0;
    var PlayerTop = 0;

    function move(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 68) {
            playerLeft += 10
            player.style.left = playerLeft + "px";
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 65) {
            playerLeft -= 10
            player.style.left = playerLeft + "px";
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 87) {
            PlayerTop -= 10
            player.style.top = PlayerTop + "px";
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 83) {
            PlayerTop += 10
            player.style.top = PlayerTop + "px";
        }
    }


    function loadEvents() {
        document.onkeydown = move;
    }
    window.onload = loadEvents;
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="field">
    <div id="player">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why window.onload works and onload="" does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27140026/why-window-onload-works-and-onload-does-not-work)

Comment: Your assignment of the player needs to ALSO be inside the onload: `var player;
function loadEvents() { player = document.getElementById("player"); document.onkeydown=move; }`
    var

Comment: @TimB - wrong duplicate!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that your want to get an element which doesn't exist yet

```
var player = document.getElementById("player");
```

Put this line in the `loadEvents()` function which is called when the window is loaded.

*Note: Avoid errors (if `#player` element doesn't exist) adding `if (player) { ... }`*

```
<script>
  var player = null;
  var playerLeft = 0;
  var playerTop = 0;

  function move(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 68) {
        playerLeft += 10
        player.style.left = playerLeft + "px";
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 65) {
        playerLeft -= 10
        player.style.left = playerLeft + "px";
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 87) {
        playerTop -= 10
        player.style.top = playerTop + "px";
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 83) {
        playerTop += 10
        player.style.top = playerTop + "px";
    }
  }


  function loadEvents() {
    player = document.getElementById("player");
    if (player) {
      document.onkeydown = move;
    }
  }
  window.onload = loadEvents;
</script>
```

---

#### Edit

For @tmslnz

> *`var player = null` is somewhat redundant, since getElementById returns null if no element is found.*

From the ECMAScript2015 spec

> **4.3.10 undefined value**
>
> primitive value used when a variable has not been assigned a value
>
> **4.3.12 null value**
>
> primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142912/when-do-i-initialize-variables-in-javascript-with-null-or-not-at-all/13143055#13143055) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980559/is-it-better-to-return-undefined-or-null-from-a-javascript-function/37980662#37980662)

Comment: In addition, `strict mode` would invalidate this.

Comment: @mplungjan Yes you right, I just pasted the code too quickly without reading myselft after. Thanks guys

Comment: I am hair-splitting, but for it's own sake: `var player = null` is somewhat redundant, since `getElementById` returns `null` if no element is found.

Answer (score 0):

This runs before the document is loaded.
AKA before the browser has any clue of your markup.

```
var player = document.getElementById("player");
…
```

Any time you are querying the DOM (think of it as the HTML you wrote as seen by the browser), you need to wait for it be `ready`.

Your script would probably be OK if you placed it at the very end of your document, before the closing `</body>` tag, because by then the browser would have had a chance to spot `#player`.

What you need to do is find a way to structure your scripts so that they don't try to access the DOM before it's ready.

The easy way is to put *everything* inside `onload` in inside `$(function(){ … })` if you are using jQuery.

Alternatively if you prefer a bit more control, you can use something like an `init` function, which you use to *"start the engine **after** the tank is filled"* (to use a crappy metaphor…)

For example:

```
var player;
var playerLeft = 0;
var playerTop = 0;

function init () {
    player = document.getElementById("player");
    loadEvents();
}

function move(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 68) {
        playerLeft += 10
        player.style.left = playerLeft + "px";
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 65) {
        playerLeft -= 10
        player.style.left = playerLeft + "px";
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 87) {
        playerTop -= 10
        player.style.top = playerTop + "px";
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 83) {
        playerTop += 10
        player.style.top = playerTop + "px";
    }
}

function loadEvents() {
    document.onkeydown = move;
}

window.onload = init;
```