# What's the difference between var myvar; and var myvar= null;?

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between

```
var myvar;
```

and

```
var myvar = null;
```

?

I've just seen both next to next in professional code and wondering what this is all about...

Comment: Simply put: `var myvar;` just declared a variable, but the variable is still `undefined`. On the other hand, `var myvar = null;` sets `myvar` to `null`.

Comment: [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) and [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) are different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One creates `myvar` (in the current scope) and assigns no value to it (leaving it `=== undefined`).

The other assigns `null` to it too.

The assignment of `null` may be significant depending on how other code interacts with the variable. OTOH, it may done for lack of understanding of what it means.

Comment: Follow up: can you set a variable to be undefined?

Comment: Yes, you can. `undefined` is property of the global scope that defaults to holding the `undefined` primitive.

Comment: Sweet - TYVM!  I've been clue-sticked!

Answer (score 0):

If you try `var myvar;` you've defined `myvar` as **undefined** that means it simply has not been assigned a value.

but when you try `var myvar = null;` you've assigned the **null literal** to the `myvar`,which means that the variable represents the null, empty, or non-existent reference.

Comment: Note that unless you use `===`, you might not notice a difference; `null` and `undefined` compare loosely equal.  But there will be some code that does care.

Comment: @cHao, yes that's true for comparison.extra rep for nice tip.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `var myvar = null;`

**Why?**

If I'm checking to see if that value is set in the future, null means that it has not been set, where as undefined means that there was probably an error while trying to set `myvar` somewhere in the code.

Heres some other opinions as well - [What reason is there to use null instead of undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604749/what-reason-is-there-to-use-null-instead-of-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: `undefined` means a value hasn't been set; it basically means "i don't know", and that's what you get if you don't specify a value.  `null` means the value was set, but was explicitly set to nothing.  As for not knowing whether your values were assigned...if you have that much of a problem knowing whether some error prevented setting a value, perhaps you're catching too many exceptions.  :P  I've never had such a problem.