# Can we declare variable value as undefined while initializing the Variable Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat in angular js,
I am having an add button where I need to just add an empty object so can i initialize variable as undefined instead of empty.

ex
my **HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="test in tests">
 <td>.....</td>
</tr>
```

**Controller**

```
function getStestItem() {
    var testItem = {
        ItemID: null,
        Test: "",
        Description: ""
    }
    $scope.tests.push(skillItem);
}
$scope.add = function(){getStestItem();}
```

so instead of giving empty values can I give as

```
function getStestItem() {
    var testItem = {
        ItemID: null,
        Test: undefined,
        Description: undefined
    }
    $scope.tests.push(skillItem);
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Don't set things to `undefined`. Reserve that value to mean "not yet set to anything". Set it to `null` instead.

Comment: Did u try to give them null values instead of "undefined"?

Comment: I Tried giving undefined, the reason i was asking for undefined is as the model scope will be undefined initially.

Comment: By definition, variables that aren't initialized are always undefined. [Read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28825847/4046274)

Comment: its same as u set the value of ItemID to "null", for more details check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101948/javascript-checking-for-null-vs-undefined-and-difference-between-and

Comment: @PirateX so is it fine giving undefined??

Comment: @Sultan Essentially null and undefined mean the same thing even though they are different values. It all depends on the convention of how you use it in your system.

Comment: @PirateX Thanks for your response, only question can the variables in angular js be initialized with undefined? Is it write way or wrong in doing so?

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  Setting a value to `undefined` is the same as not supplying it at all.  Since JavaScript objects are dynamic and properties can be added and removed at any time, providing properties that are `undefined` is redundant.

Comment: @Sultan Use `NULL` because it is now the trend/industry adopted standards. However I personally prefer to let things be undefined.

Comment: @Claies: I am adding an empty model on click of add button using ng-repeat, my only question is while I am trying to add an model, so i am asking what is the best practice to add a model from controller, to give empty value or keep it as undefined?

Comment: @PirateX: Thanks, that's what i was also preferring just wanted to know what is the best practice.

Comment: Yes, it's clear you are adding an empty model.  That's the point.  You don't need to add things that don't exist, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @PirateX you can add flag if it is an question that helps other as well.

Comment: Then how would i add gimme an example . @Claies

Comment: what you have is **identical** to if you did `var testItem = {}`.  There is almost never a reason to add properties to the object if they don't have a value;  the property will be dynamically added to the object when a value is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

This will be too much for a comment, So I will leave it as a answer here

null is slightly more specific than undefined: It's a blank object reference. JavaScript is loosely typed, of course, but not all of the things JavaScript interacts with are loosely typed.
 ***If an API like the DOM in browsers needs an object reference that's blank, we use null, not undefined***.
 And similarly, the DOM's getElementById operation returns an object reference — either a valid one (if it found the DOM element), or null (if it didn't).

This answer is not a mine, for more details [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101948/javascript-checking-for-null-vs-undefined-and-difference-between-and)
 Hope this helps