# What should I return when object is not found in TypeScript using strict mode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, strictnullchecks

Here's the snippet of code in typescript with `strictNullChecks: true`

```
getItem(key: string): T {
    let index: number = this.contains(key); // returns -1 if not found
    if (index === -1) {
        return null; // error null is not assignable to type 'T'
    } 
    return this.map[index].value;
  }
```

As you can see I can't return null when I didn't find element because of a compilation error:

> error 'null' is not assignable to type 'T'

What should I return instead of null? What is the best practice?

Comment: Why not just change the return type annotation to include `null`? EG: `getItem(key: string): T | null { ... }`?

Comment: how about allowing the function to return `T` _or_ null? `getItem(key: string): T | null` - as a side-note, I never, _ever_ use `null` in javascript / typescript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8940

Comment: is it the best practice ? What you use instead of null when you never ever use null ?

Comment: In your specific example, I would use either `false`or `undefined`, depending on the contents of your map.  I believe it's "better practice", but don't have an authoritative source for that belief.  Some data points: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8940 and https://www.thecodeship.com/web-development/the-undefined-vs-null-pitfall-in-javascript/  and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28825847 - using null requires additional work / complexity when checking values...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With strict null checks, any function that is returning something which could be 'not found' should have return type declared as `Something | undefined`, and it should return `undefined` value in "not found" case.

It's also possible to use `null` instead of `undefined`, both as type and as return value, but the choice was made and TypeScript type system uses `undefined`, not `null` for representing uninitialized and optional values - for example, the type of optional property (declared with `?` sign) is `T | undefined`.

See also [this quote](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8940#issuecomment-223344607) mentioned by user cale_b in comments:

> the rational is JavaScript has two concepts to refer to the empty
>   sentinel value, most other programming languages just have one.
>   Moreover, undefined is always present, as all uninitialized values
>   have the value undefined at run time. null on the other hand is
>   avoidable, specially if you are not using any APIs that produce it,
>   e.g. DOM, which the TypeScript compiler does not use.