# Is there a difference between typeof x === 'undefined' vs if (x)

Tags: javascript

I've always maintained the practice of checking if a value is undefined using

```
if (typeof x === 'undefined')
```

However, a colleague is suggesting that using `if (x) {` is better.

Is there any difference between these two methods from a computational point of view?

Comment: These are not equivalent (and also not inverses of each other). `if(x)` checks for [truthy values](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Truthy); the other one checks for `undefined`, specifically. But then, `if(x === undefined)` is easier.

Comment: You should view this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604749/what-reason-is-there-to-use-null-instead-of-undefined-in-javascript has a detailed answers with the benefits of `undefined`

Comment: @jtwalters it's not relevant

Comment: Depending on the context, for parameters, I tend to use `x == null` to cover both the use case of `null` and `undefined`. It ensures a boolean output and its cross-language is more descriptive and readable.

Comment: As @SebastianSimon got at, you should basically never use `typeof x === 'undefined'`. `x === undefined`, however, is a nice and specific check when you don’t need general falsiness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two differences off the top of my mind:

1. Checking the type as undefined only checks for undefined, unlike `if(x)`, which checks for any truthy values (e.g. `true`, a non-empty string, a non-zero number, etc)
2. You can perform `typeof` on non-existent variables, even in strict mode. You'll get a reference error if you never declared `x` and did `if(x)`

```js
"use strict";

const a = undefined;
const b = "truthy value";

if(a) {
  console.log("a in if"); // never executes
}
if(typeof a !== "undefined") {
  console.log("a with typeof"); // never executes
}

if(b) {
  console.log("b in if"); // executes
}
if(typeof b === "undefined") {
  console.log("b with typeof"); // never executes
}


try {
  if(c) console.log("this should error");
} catch(e) {
  console.log("Can't access non-existent variable");
}

console.log("No error:", typeof c);
```

#### When should I use which one?

Generally:
**Use `if(x)` when...**

- You're checking for a boolean
- You're checking for (not) `0`
- You're checking for a non-empty empty string (*probably use `if(string.length)` instead*)
- Checking the return value of a function (e.g. a function returns `null` when there's no result for a query or an object when there is (DOM functions like `document.getElementById` return null when no element with that ID exists))

**Use `if(typeof x !== "undefined")` when...**

- You're checking whether an object key exists (`if(typeof obj.key !== "undefined")`) (the proper way as a commentator pointed out is with [`Object.hasOwn(obj, "key")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn))
- You're checking whether a variable exists (not sure when or why you would do that though)
- Checking whether an argument has been passed
- Other uses like when you're writing an Express server and checking user-provided content
- Something else I probably forgot...

Comment: Another important use case of `if(x)` is to check whether an object exists. Lots of functions return either an object or `null` (or either an object or `undefined`). Especially HTML elements. Key membership should be checked with [`Object.hasOwn(obj, "key")`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn), not with `in`. The arguments use case is very useful indeed.

Comment: @SebastianSimon right, I'll make the updates.

Comment: Hey @code -  I just wanted to note that it seems that the following works:
`let obj = {test1: "test1", test2: "test2"};
if (!obj.test3) { console.log('nice'); }`


Is there any instance where this may fall short?

Comment: @OliverKucharzewski `if(x)` checks for falsy values. `undefined` is also a `falsy` values, so while it will not execute when something is undefined, neither will it when the value is `false`, `""`, or `null`. `obj.test3` is `undefined`, which coerces to false. When you flip that, it will be true. `if` will see `true`, which is why it executes. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Thats completely fair, thanks @code :)

Answer (score -1):

Something that's useful to keep in mind is that Javascript is dynamically typed, even if it looks like it's just variables. [There are a handful of types in JS](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types), and Undefined (with caps) is one, and the only value it can hold is `undefined`. Think of it like saying you have the Number type and it only accepts 42. This is important to know because JS engines have to observe spec.

> The Undefined type has exactly one value, called undefined. **Any variable that has not been assigned a value has the value undefined**.

There is a lot of variation in application code, but you can know that variables that have not been assigned are of type Undefined with value `undefined` and not something else. Next to Undefined is Null, which has a single value, `null`. Null, unlike Undefined, needs to be assigned.

[In the spec you'll also the find the table for the result you get for each variable type.](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-typeof-operator)

You'll notice that Undefined has its own return value, as well as Boolean, but [Null returns `"object"`, which is reported to be a mistake in the original spec that we can't get rid of](https://2ality.com/2013/10/typeof-null.html).

With types out of the way, we get to Boolean coercion, which is how if statements work out the condition. [The spec has a table of cases that define when a value should be coerced into `true` or `false`.](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#table-toboolean-conversions)

You'll see that an `if` clause receives the Undefined type, it returns `false`. The same happens with Null. There are a few other cases that can also return false even if they are not Undefined or Null.

1. The Number type with values `0`, `-0`, `NaN`
2. The String type with length 0 (`""`)
3. The BigInt type with value 0

As others have already answered, applications of the spec come in a few different places. The reasons as for why `typeof` exists and there is an overlap with the falsey evaluation arise from how the JS engines handle values and perform coercion into Boolean.