# React not recognizing a "0" as a typed value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI form which I am disabling the submit button until all fields are filled out,  The problem is, some of the fields in the form may need to have a "0" value, but if you simply type in a "0" it won't accept it as a value.  If you type anything after the 0 it will accept the value and enable the button.  What am I doing wrong and how can I correct this?

```
const disabled = (!values.name || !values.avgRunTime || !values.avgSetupTime);


    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setValues({
            ...values,
             [name]: ( typeof value === 'string' ? (value).replace(/ +(?= )/g, '').trimStart() : value ) 
        });
    };


    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
           <Input
                type='text'
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                name='name'
                label='Name'
                value={values.name}
           />

           <Input
               type='text'
               onChange={handleInputChange}
               name='avgRunTime'
               label='Avg. Run Time'
               value={values.avgRunTime} 
          />

          <Input
               type='text'
               onChange={handleInputChange}
               name='avgSetupTime'
               label='Avg. Setup Time'
               value={values.avgSetupTime}
          />

          <Button
              type='submit'
              text='Submit'
              onClick={handleSubmit}
              disabled={disabled}
          />
      </Form>
    );
}
```

!values.*** should only disable the button if the value is null or undefined, correct?  0 should count as in value, since it has been typed in, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0` is falsy in JavaScript, so it will evaluate `disabled` to `true`:

```js
const values = {
  name: "Something",
  avgRunTime: 2500,
  avgSetupTime: 0
}

const disabled = (!values.name || !values.avgRunTime || !values.avgSetupTime);

// false
console.log(`name: ${!values.name}`);
// false
console.log(`avgRunTime: ${!values.avgRunTime}`);
// true
console.log(`avgSetupTime: ${!values.avgSetupTime}`);
// true
console.log(`disabled: ${disabled}`)
```

Instead, it's probably best to have the unset value be `null` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6604783/4816918)), and do a null check (`=== null`) instead of a falsy check.

Comment: Jeff, that is a good idea.  I also thought about changing it to something like "values.avgSetupTime.length < 1".  That was it would recognize the 0 as a character.