# Null and undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

In Javascript i have read that we can define our own value for `undefined`. Initially `undefined == null` is `true`.

1. After we change the value of `undefined` will `undefined == null` still be `true`?
2. By assigning our own value to `undefined` does it mean that we can assign real numbers to it?
3. Why are there two absence of value thingies like `null` and `undefined`?  Couldn't we just do with one? Is there any difference between them?

Comment: The first question can't be answered unless you say what you set the value of the variable `undefined` to. For the last question(s), see [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/)

Comment: Who told you that you could change undefined?

Comment: For last question(s), see also [Why is there a `null` value in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461966/).

Comment: `undefined` is not a variable like many of the below answers state. Just because in older versions of ECMA script it is writable, and just because it was a valid identifier in older versions of ECMA script, does not make it a variable. It is a data type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`undefined` is a variable on the global object which is `window` in browser environments. Its initial value is the primitive `undefined`.

Being a property on the global object, historically you could have changed its value as,

```
window.undefined = "42"; // or just undefined = "42"
```

The meaning of life is now clearly defined. But since EcmaScript-5 is out, this has been disallowed, and even though it is still a property of the global object, it has been made non-writable now.

The primitives `null` and `undefined` are not the same thing if no tampering has occurred.

`Null` is a data type that has the sole value `null`. `Undefined` is another data type whose sole value is the primitive `undefined`. You can verify whether they represent the same object or not easily.

```
null === undefined // false
```

However,

```
null == undefined // true
```

is true, because they are both casted to the boolean value `false` before a comparison is made. The rules for converting both these values to boolean are clearly defined in section 9.2 of the spec.

```
9.2 ToBoolean

Argument Type | Result
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Undefined     | false
Null          | false
Boolean       | The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
Number        | ..
String        | ..
Object        | ..
```

Comment: Note that, in Chrome 16, `window.undefined` is writeable.  In 18, it's not (not sure about 17).

Comment: @AndyE - thanks for the heads up. Just tested in Chrome 17 - its not-writable.

Answer (score 4):

Note that in older JS versions, `undefined` isn't a keyword the way `null` is. You can define a value for `undefined` because it's just a variable.

```
var null; // syntax error
null = 0; // another error
var undefined; // not an error
undefined = null; //not an error
```

However, doing this is a bad idea, as it could break things in 3rd party code that you use. ECMAScript 5 defines a read-only [`undefined` property](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.1.3) on the [global object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1) (note: still not a keyword), so you can't assign to it in ES5 compliant JS implementations.

As for whether `undefined == null` after assigning a value to `null`, just like `foo == null` it depends entirely on the value you assign to `undefined`.

Comment: Note that, in Chrome 16/V8, the `undefined` property is set to writeable, so you still can't rely on it.

Comment: @AndyE: at this point, I don't believe any browser is fully ES5 compliant, which is why I didn't mention any specific browsers.

Answer (score 4):

> But after we change the value of undefined will undefined == null still be true?

That depends what you change it to.  If you change it to `null`, then yes.  If you change it to anything else, then no.  Just don't change it.

> And by assigning our own value to undefined does it mean that we can assign real numbers to it?

Well, yes.  Didn't you try it?

> Lastly why are there two absence of value thingies like null and undefined? Couldn't we just do with one? Is there any difference between them?

`undefined` means that a value has not been assigned or there's no defined value.  `null` means that there is a value, but that value is `null`.  So, yes, there's a difference.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript undefined means a declared variable but not yet assigned value.

Null is a value so a var = null is a defined variable.

Try to read this [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript)