# Why can't a property be added to a null value?

Tags: javascript, properties, null, typeerror

If `null` value of javascript is an empty object so why can't add a property to it?
the below code clears my question:

```
var a = null;

typeof a;
>>> "object"

a.name = 'name';
>>> TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of null

var a = new Object();

typeof a;
>>> "object"

a.name = 'name';
>>> "name"
```

Comment: `null` is not an "empty object", despite what the `typeof` operator evaluates to.

Comment: "I had to be done in ten days or something worse than JavaScript would have happened." - Brendan Eich

Comment: I think what may be confusing about this is that `typeof null` returns `"object"` although `null` is _not_ actually an object.

Comment: I really wish I could close this as a duplicate, but try as I might, I can only find "specific implementation errors" and not a similar general question. In any case,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461966/why-is-there-a-null-value-in-javascript is an interesting read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition neither the `null` value nor the `undefined` value have any properties, nor can any properties be added to them.

This is summarized nicely for [null](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.11):

> primitive *value* that represents the intentional absence of any object value.

And likewise, for [undefined](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.9):

> primitive value used when a variable has not been assigned a value.

(`null` is the only value of the Null-type and `undefined` is the only value of the Undefined-type.)

### Now, for the implementation goodies:

Both of these types represent *primitives* and the behavior of "primitiveValue.Property" is covered by the internal ToObject method. (See [GetValue/PutValue](http://es5.github.com/#x8.7.1) for the start of the rabbit hole.)

From [9.9: ToObject](http://es5.github.com/#x9.9):

> The abstract operation ToObject converts its argument to a value of type Object according to ..

> - Undefined => Throw a TypeError exception.

- Null => **Throw a TypeError exception.**
- (and so on)

As far as the comments, see [11.4.3: The typeOf Operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.3):

> Return a String determined by Type(val) according to ..

> - Undefined => "undefined"

- Null => **"object"**
- (and so on)

Comment: In other words, the question is based on a false premise: neither `null` nor `undefined` are empty objects.

Comment: `typeof null === 'object'` is one of the weird JSWTF quirks. It's odd, and it doesn't mean what you think it does.

Comment: It's a quirk that stands since the first implementations of JavaScript. [It *may* be rectified in the next version of ECMAScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#null) by opt-in and will give `typeof null === "null"`.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Well, it was proposed, but [was also rejected](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:typeof_null).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Just great, they don't know what it's supposed to be yet. Updated my comment. :-P

Comment: This is a sentence in the "Professional Javascript for web developers, Nicholas C. Zakas": "Logically, a null value is an empty object pointer, which is why typeof returns “object” when it’s passed a null value". I am really confused about it. null is a primitive type but actually it is a pointer to an empty object!

Comment: @MustafaShujaie The standard's description of the [`null` value](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.11) may be more useful: "*primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value.*" And, it doesn't really explain *why* an "*absence*" is yet an `"object"`, but it does cover the rules that determine the response from the [`typeof` Operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.3).

Comment: @MustafaShujaie As noted in the comments (and I have updated in my answer), `typeof null` returning "object" is only for historical reasons/compatibility at this point. It *would* make much more sense if it returned "null", just as `typeof undefined` evaluates to "undefined". But, as per the specification, it does not. Do not take this to mean that `null` is an object; it is only a primitive value and `null` is most certainly *not* a "pointer".

Answer (score 1):

`null` is an object in Javascript that represents the absence of an object. You cannot add a property to nothing.

See also: [Why is null an object and what's the difference between null and undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/null-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Null is not an object, it is a primitive value of type Null.