# JavaScript: What is the data type of null?

Tags: javascript, null, typeof

It is said that `null`, in JavaScript, is a primary type. However, when I use the operator `typeof` on `null`, it returns `"Object"`.

What is the underlying procedure that made `typeof` to return `"Object"` instead of `"Primitive"` or `"null"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of null is object.

you can check type of any variable with `typeof` keyword.
for example

```
typeof null
```

check the [link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l9wHAAQ) below for more details.

Comment: if null is an object, why can't I add a property to it?

Comment: because By definition neither the null value nor the undefined value have any properties, nor can any properties be added to them.

Comment: have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346237/why-cant-a-property-be-added-to-a-null-value

Comment: @DatV. you need to accept the answer if I helped.

Comment: According to the spec, this is incorrect. [`null` is an instance of the type "Null"](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-null-type). The unexpected `typeof null` value was chosen for enhanced compatibility with Java.

Comment: @BenAston the answer is for Javascript not Java.

Comment: Yes, I know. [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64009911/38522).

Comment: The question was: "what is the data type of null". The answer is in the spec:
https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-8.2