# Initializing global variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, null, global-variables, undefined

If I have the following line at the top of my `.js` file how come when I call a function that uses `clickButton` it says it's `null`?

**In the HTML**

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="toggle()" id="txt1" />
<input name="aButton" id="aButton" type="button" value="ButtonVal" />
```

**In the JS**

```
//global variables
var clickButton = document.getElementById("aButton")
var state = false

function toggle()
{
  if(!state)
      /*here it says clickButton is null but if I put var clickButton = 
      document.getElementById("aButton") in this scope it works*/
      clickButton.disabled = true
  else
    clickButton.disabled = false
}
```

Also what is the *difference* (not how I check) between null and undefined? Is it that null has been declared but not assigned a value, where as undefined hasn't even been declared?

I mean [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461966/why-is-there-a-null-value-in-javascript) says "A property to which a programmer has not assigned anything will be undefined, but in order for a property to become null, null must be explicitly assigned to it." but I can guarantee you that I never explicitly assigned null to anything.

Comment: +1 for the second part of the question ;)

Comment: `null` and `undefined` are simply some (different) values. There is no further meaning.

Comment: Post all of your code. `undefined` can mean that a variable isn't defined *or* the variable is defined but has the value `undefined`. It's valid to do `var x = undefined;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that `document.getElementById("aButton")` is returning null. The element with the specified id is not available in the dom or your dom is not ready yet- see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById.

For null vs undefined - refer to [What is the difference between the mouseover and mouseenter events?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1104344/1048572)

Comment: Why would it not be accessible by the DOM? If I had the same line of code inside a function it works (are you basically saying I have a typo in my code).

Comment: @Celeritas: That's not what #hop is saying, you need to wait until the DOM is ready to manipulate it right?

Answer (score 0):

#### First Question

- Be sure that you have a markup like this in your html file:

  ```
   <input name="aButton" id="aButton" type="button" value="ButtonVal" />
  ```
- Be sure that you call the function once the DOM is ready. So, put the link the js in the bottom of your html page. Or inside this:

  ```
   if (document.readyState === "complete") { //codehere }
  ```

#### Second Question

In JavaScript an `undefined` variable is a variable that as never been declared, or never assigned a value. Let's say you declare `var a` for instance, then a will be `undefined`, because it was never assigned any value.

But if you then assign `a = null` then `a` will now be null. In JavaScript null is an object (try `typeof null` in a JavaScript console if you don't believe me), which means that `null` is a value (in fact even `undefined` is a value).

You may use those operators to check between undefined an null. For example:

```
null === null            # => true
undefined === undefined  # => true
undefined === null       # => false
undefined == null        # => true
```

More? [What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076944/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: @Celeritas In most cases, means that the [DOM hierarchy](http://webdesign.about.com/od/dom/a/aa120202a.htm) has been fully constructed.

Answer (score -1):

undefined and null are indeed two different types.
null is an object and refers to a variable which has been declared but provided a null value whereas undefined in an undeclared variable and is not an object in and of itself.

My guess is you haven't waited for the DOM to be ready so your clickButton variable is attempting to grab an element too early and getting null. Try wrapping it in document.ready or window.onload so that it executes when the DOM is finished loading :-).

```
window.onload(function() {
    var clickButton = document.getElementById("aButton");
});
```