# why undefined is a data type

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

I have learnt recently while debugging, that undefined is a data type and null is an object.

I think both of them comes under datatypes.

I checked the **typeof undefined** and **typeof null**. They returned **"undefined"** and **"object"** respectively.

```
typeof undefined 
"undefined"

typeof null
"object"
```

Could some body explain why is this strange behaviour.

Comment: do you expect that  typeof null === 'null' ? ^^

Comment: @john Smith No, But I did not expect this behaviour

Comment: @Venky: When there is a behaviour you did not expect, you should explain what behaviour you expected _instead_. Otherwise we can't help you...

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Here basically I thought null to be null and undefined to be undefined ( as of native primitives). But one found out to be a object type.

Comment: They are both built-in keywords. But every entity has a type, and creating a new type for `null` when it already fits into the type system perfectly well would be a backward step.

Comment: Actually @LightnessRacesinOrbit `undefined` is not a built in keyword. (another mistake imo - this is why you see people do `void 0`)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Oh, _that_'s a JS bug then >.<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typeof null` being object is an early mistake - [when they tried correcting it in a Chrome nightly (to `typeof null === "null"` )](https://web.archive.org/web/20160331031419/http://wiki.ecmascript.org:80/doku.php?id=harmony:typeof_null) too many things relied on the current behavior and too much code broke.

JavaScript objects that are not set to normal values generally have three states:

1. Undeclared.
2. Undefined.
3. Explicitly nothing.

#### Undeclared

For example - this case:

```
 y++; //I did not declare y before, this causes a reference error
 y === 'undefined'; //still a reference error 
 typeof y; //'undefined', since typeof is an operator and not a function.
```

Basically, an undeclared variable is in the state 'the script does not know this variable'.

#### Undefined

This means that the the runtime 'knows this variable' but it wasn't set to anything yet. Or, as the language specification puts this:

> undefined value - primitive value used when a variable has not been assigned a value.

For example:

```
 var y; //y is undefined
 y === undefined; //true, y defined the line above
 typeof y; //undefined, but this is redundant, just do `=== undefined`
 (function(x){ /* x is undefined here as it was set to nothing*/})()
```

#### Explicitly nothing

When you have something that is *supposed* to have a value but you want to declare that it is nothing. Or, as the language specification puts this:

> null value - primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value.

For example, `document.getElementById("foo");` returns `null` if the element with the given ID is not in the DOM to indicate *explicitly nothing* was returned. Constrast this with functions that have no return statements so they return `undefined` which is the default.

Comment: Thanks, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Venky sorry, had to go, will elaborate.

Comment: So are you're saying it's a Chrome bug? Or are you saying that Chrome leads JavaScript development in this area?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's a JavaScript bug, there was discussion in the working group (TC39) and in ESDiscuss (mailing list) about fixing this - it was attempted in Chrome canary and the experience failed.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Wish I'd known about that discussion at the time; I'd have submitted some comments. This behaviour is perfectly reasonable as it is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Enjoy https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2013-July/032282.html . Also, feel free to bring up your arguments on ESDiscuss

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Thanks; I'll have a gander through all that when time allows :)

Answer (score 2):

**They have different types for the same reason that they *both* exist: `undefined` and `null` are conceptually not the same thing.**

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/462000/560648) puts it:

> undefined is the lack of a type and value, and null is the lack of a value.

But I prefer to apply a real-world analogy: matter *vs* dark matter.

`undefined` is like matter that does not exist. It has no form or substance, and therefore has no meaningful type. You set something to `undefined` when that thing should not be deemed as existing.

`null`, on the other hand, right across the realm of Computer Science, describes an object of an unknown state. It's still an object, but we don't know *what* object or what its value is. (In this sense it is similar to the numeric `NaN` which is still conceptually a number: we just don't know *what* number.) **Nullity serves a placeholder for an unknown value, not for something that has no value.** It's dark matter that *does* exist, in the form of an *object*, but no further information about its type is available since we don't have any information on it.

JavaScript understands this. So, historically, `typeof null` has been `'object'` and `typeof undefined` has been `'undefined'`.

[Some people say this is a legacy bug](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:typeof_null) since the dawn of JavaScript; I prefer to say that it's common sense from the dawn of JavaScript.

What *is* a bug in JavaScript is that `null === null`, and `var o = {x:undefined}; 'x' in o; // true`, neither of which should be the case.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that 'those people' who say it's a legacy bug are the language creators. What you say is an interesting take on it, but it's simply not what the people who wrote the language meant or are working on it now think. It's also worth mentioning that it is not what the language specification states. I agree that `null !== null` would be a really interesting experiment, I don't see any case except `maybeNull === null` where `null === null` makes much sense in a high-level point of view. also note for example `o = {x:undefined}` means `'x' in o; // true` but `'y' in o; // false`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yes, I think the link under that sentence makes clear it is the working group who is of this opinion. However, it doesn't really matter to me who they are or what they created — I disagree with them either way. As for the latter example, I consider that to be a language bug; it should be `false` in both cases.

Comment: You don't have to like the language or any design choice the comittee made but it is what it is. I strongly encourage you to participate and voice your concerns and opinions :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Then it's further worth mentioning that the ECMAScript creators did not invent the concept of nullity, nor of undefinedness. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) this is the reason they give for `null` being an object:

```
typeof null === 'object'; // This stands since the beginning of JavaScript
```

Yeah! That is a good reason... I guess they don't understand it themselves, and therefore a design error.