# Why do we need undefined in JavaScript? What is the purpose of it?

Tags: javascript

I cannot grasp an idea of undefined. I know what undefined is, I know what null is but what's the point of having undefined?  Obviously, coming from another language where if the variable is not used it's pointing to a dummy location in memory aka null. If the variable is not assigned any value, it gets assigned null until you assign another value to it. However, I cannot understand what is the purpose of undefined in JS if null exist.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: these responses may be helpful 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101107/what-exactly-undefined-means-in-javascript-why-its-there-what-usages-it-has

Comment: Also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/463608/567595

Comment: I have a related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37980662/2079345

Comment: From the specification: [_“null value: primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value”_](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-null-value), [_“undefined value: primitive value used when a variable has not been assigned a value”_](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-undefined-value), but it’s also used as the return value of a function that doesn’t return anything, or the result of the completion record of various declarations, etc.